# Lists and data.frame combine (same row, but different length of each column)

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

How to combine different Lists and data.frame (same row, but different length of each column) in R?

I have tow LISTs and one data.frame, COL01, COL02 and COL03, I want to combine them into one data.frame

```
COL01 =
structure(list(V1 = c(-0.0431597784900261, -0.518148142834806, 
-0.237032580263406, -0.920434206514568, -0.95436194682491, -0.556922703189482
), V2 = c(-0.518148142834806, -0.237032580263406, -0.920434206514568, 
-0.95436194682491, -0.556922703189482), V3 = c(-0.237032580263406, 
-0.920434206514568, -0.95436194682491, -0.556922703189482, -0.988289687135251
), V4 = c(-0.920434206514568, -0.95436194682491, -0.556922703189482, 
-0.988289687135251, 0.0569519413796151), V5 = c(-0.95436194682491, 
-0.556922703189482, -0.988289687135251, 0.0569519413796151, 0.0981633964482812
), V6 = c(-0.95436194682491, -0.556922703189482, -0.988289687135251, 
0.0569519413796151, 0.0981633964482812, -1.60696055701778)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"))

COL02 = 
structure(list(V1 = c(0.490280732997843, -0.232516232554677, 
0.237972180098397, -0.988223009354951, -1.33316658650733, -0.603056329566425
), V2 = c(-0.232516232554677, 0.237972180098397, -0.988223009354951, 
-1.33316658650733, -0.603056329566425), V3 = c(0.237972180098397, 
-0.988223009354951, -1.33316658650733, -0.603056329566425, -0.999192946437536
), V4 = c(-0.988223009354951, -1.33316658650733, -0.603056329566425, 
-0.999192946437536, 0.00282420705837356), V5 = c(-1.33316658650733, 
-0.603056329566425, -0.999192946437536, 0.00282420705837356, 
-0.138063379339347), V6 = c(-1.33316658650733, -0.603056329566425, 
-0.999192946437536, 0.00282420705837356, -0.138063379339347, 
-1.57598823020269)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", 
"V6"))

COL03 <- structure(list(LONGITUDE = c(52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5
), LATITUDE = c(-2.5, -2.5, -2.5, -2.5, -2.5, -2.5), DATE_START = structure(c(1358812800, 
1358899200, 1358985600, 1359072000, 1359158400, 1359244800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), DATE_END = structure(c(1359417600, 1359504000, 1359590400, 
1359676800, 1359763200, 1359849600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
)), FLAG = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)), .Names = c("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE", 
"DATE_START", "DATE_END", "FLAG"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The result I expect is a data frame with 2 list columns and one data frame

```
     COL01                                                                           COL02                                                                            LONGITUDE LATITUDE DATE_START   DATE_END FLAG 
1      -0.04315978 -0.51814814 -0.23703258 -0.92043421 -0.95436195 -0.55692270         0.4902807 -0.2325162  0.2379722 -0.9882230 -1.3331666 -0.6030563                   52.5     -2.5 2013-01-22 2013-01-29    4     
2      -0.5181481 -0.2370326 -0.9204342 -0.9543619 -0.5569227                          -0.2325162  0.2379722 -0.9882230 -1.3331666 -0.6030563                             52.5     -2.5 2013-01-23 2013-01-30    4     
3      -0.2370326 -0.9204342 -0.9543619 -0.5569227 -0.9882897                          0.2379722 -0.9882230 -1.3331666 -0.6030563 -0.9991929                              52.5     -2.5 2013-01-24 2013-01-31    4     
4      -0.92043421 -0.95436195 -0.55692270 -0.98828969  0.05695194                     -0.988223009 -1.333166587 -0.603056330 -0.999192946  0.002824207                   52.5     -2.5 2013-01-25 2013-02-01    4     
5      -0.95436195 -0.55692270 -0.98828969  0.05695194  0.09816340                     -1.333166587 -0.603056330 -0.999192946  0.002824207 -0.138063379                   52.5     -2.5 2013-01-26 2013-02-02    4     
6      -0.95436195 -0.55692270 -0.98828969  0.05695194  0.09816340 -1.60696056         -1.333166587 -0.603056330 -0.999192946  0.002824207 -0.138063379 -1.575988230      52.5     -2.5 2013-01-27 2013-02-03    4
```

Comment: Do you expect a data frame with 2 list columns?

Comment: Um, `data.table(COL01, COL02)`

Comment: yes,I expect a data frame with 2 list columns

Comment: thanks, I have updated my post

Comment: `cbind(data.table(COL01, COL02), COL03)`. You generally shouldn't change your question after an answer is posted unless the answerer is okay with it. (I mean Luis, below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this help you

```
COL01 =
        structure(list(V1 = c(-0.0431597784900261, -0.518148142834806, 
                              -0.237032580263406, -0.920434206514568, -0.95436194682491, -0.556922703189482
        ), V2 = c(-0.518148142834806, -0.237032580263406, -0.920434206514568, 
                  -0.95436194682491, -0.556922703189482), V3 = c(-0.237032580263406, 
                                                                 -0.920434206514568, -0.95436194682491, -0.556922703189482, -0.988289687135251
                  ), V4 = c(-0.920434206514568, -0.95436194682491, -0.556922703189482, 
                            -0.988289687135251, 0.0569519413796151), V5 = c(-0.95436194682491, 
                                                                            -0.556922703189482, -0.988289687135251, 0.0569519413796151, 0.0981633964482812
                            ), V6 = c(-0.95436194682491, -0.556922703189482, -0.988289687135251, 
                                      0.0569519413796151, 0.0981633964482812, -1.60696055701778)), .Names = c("V1", 
                                                                                                              "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"))

COL02 = 
        structure(list(V1 = c(0.490280732997843, -0.232516232554677, 
                              0.237972180098397, -0.988223009354951, -1.33316658650733, -0.603056329566425
        ), V2 = c(-0.232516232554677, 0.237972180098397, -0.988223009354951, 
                  -1.33316658650733, -0.603056329566425), V3 = c(0.237972180098397, 
                                                                 -0.988223009354951, -1.33316658650733, -0.603056329566425, -0.999192946437536
                  ), V4 = c(-0.988223009354951, -1.33316658650733, -0.603056329566425, 
                            -0.999192946437536, 0.00282420705837356), V5 = c(-1.33316658650733, 
                                                                             -0.603056329566425, -0.999192946437536, 0.00282420705837356, 
                                                                             -0.138063379339347), V6 = c(-1.33316658650733, -0.603056329566425, 
                                                                                                         -0.999192946437536, 0.00282420705837356, -0.138063379339347, 
                                                                                                         -1.57598823020269)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", 
                                                                                                                                         "V6"))

col_1 <- unlist(lapply(COL01, paste, collapse=" "))

col_2 <- unlist(lapply(COL02, paste, collapse=" "))

df <- data.frame(col_1, col_2)

str(df)
```

You get a data frame with two columns and six rows

```
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ COl_1: Factor w/ 6 levels "-0.0431597784900261 -0.518148142834806 -0.237032580263406 -0.920434206514568 -0.95436194682491 -0.556922703189482",..: 1 3 2 4 5 6
 $ col_2: Factor w/ 6 levels "-0.232516232554677 0.237972180098397 -0.988223009354951 -1.33316658650733 -0.603056329566425",..: 6 1 5 2 3 4
```

Comment: I expect a data frame with 2 list columns